# JS canva code has horrible performance on firefox, works fine on chomium

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

I basically have 3 curved bezier lines rotating around with a somewhat dynamic background.
It is done in 2D canvas, it works fine in chromium, but in Firefox I get 1 FPS for some reason.
I tried various solutions but while some did give me like 20% performance increase, 1.2 FPS is still unacceptable.

[Here](https://codepen.io/axydavid/pen/yLxNQzQ?editors=1010) is the codepen with the code.

```
class BG {
    animationContainer = null;
    options = {
        rotation: 45,
        waves: 3,
        width: 300,
        hue: [14, 50],
        amplitude: .5,
        background: 1,
        preload: 1,
        speed: [.001, .004]
    };
    waves = [];
    hue = 0;
    hueFw = true;
    canvas = null;
    ctx = null;
    observer = null;
    radius = 0;
    centerX = 0;
    centerY = 0;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
    scale = 1;
    isVisible = false;
    gradient = null;
    color = "#000000";
    constructor(t, e) {
        this.animationContainer = t, this.options = {
            rotation: e.rotation || 45,
            waves: e.waves || 2,
            width: e.width || 300,
            hue: e.hue || [17, 50],
            amplitude: e.amplitude || .75,
            background: e.background || 1,
            preload: e.preload || 1,
            speed: e.speed || [.001, .004]
        }, this.waves = [], this.hue = this.options.hue[0], this.hueFw = true, this.setup(), this.render()
    }
    setup() {
        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"), this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d"), this.animationContainer.appendChild(this.canvas), this.resize(), window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this)), this.waves = [];
        for (let t = 0; t < this.options.waves; t++) this.waves.push(WV(this));
        this.options.preload && this.preload(), this.addIntersection()
    }
    resize() {
        let {
            offsetWidth: t,
            offsetHeight: e
        } = this.animationContainer;
        this.scale = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, this.width = t * this.scale, this.height = e * this.scale, this.canvas.width = this.width, this.canvas.height = this.height, this.canvas.style.width = `${t}px`, this.canvas.style.height = `${e}px`, this.radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.width, 2) + Math.pow(this.height, 2)) / 2, this.centerX = this.width / 2, this.centerY = this.height / 2;
    }
    addIntersection() {
        this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(t => {
            for (let e of t) this.isVisible = e.intersectionRatio > 0
        }), this.observer.observe(this.animationContainer)
    }
    preload() {
        for (let t = 0; t < this.options.waves; t++) {
            this.updateColor();
            for (let e = 0; e < this.options.width; e++) this.waves[t].update()
        }
    }
    updateColor() {
        this.hue += this.hueFw ? .01 : -.01, this.hue > this.options.hue[1] && this.hueFw ? this.hueFw = false : this.hue < this.options.hue[0] && !this.hueFw && (this.hueFw = true);
        let t = Math.floor(127 * Math.sin(.3 * this.hue) + 128),
            e = Math.floor(127 * Math.sin(.3 * this.hue + 2) + 128),
            i = Math.floor(127 * Math.sin(.3 * this.hue + 4) + 128);
        this.color = "rgba(" + t + "," + e + "," + i + ", 0.1)"
    }
    render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            if (this.isVisible) {
                this.draw();
            }
            this.render();
        });
    }
    draw() {
        for (let t of (this.updateColor(), this.clear(), this.options.background && this.background(), this.waves)) t.update(), t.draw()
    }
    clear() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }
    background() {
        this.gradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, this.height), this.gradient.addColorStop(1, "#0E1218"), this.gradient.addColorStop(0, this.color), this.ctx.fillStyle = this.gradient, this.ctx.fillRect(1, 0, this.width, this.height)
    }
}
function LN(t, e) {
    t.angle[0] += t.speed[0];
    t.angle[1] += t.speed[1];
    t.angle[2] += t.speed[2];
    t.angle[3] += t.speed[3];
    return { angle: [Math.sin(t.angle[0]), Math.sin(t.angle[1]), Math.sin(t.angle[2]), Math.sin(t.angle[3])], wave: t, color: e };
}

function rng(t, e) {
    return null == e ? Math.random() * t : t + Math.random() * (e - t);
}

function dr() {
    return Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1;
}

function WV(t) {
    let e = [];
    const angles = [
        rng(2 * Math.PI),
        rng(2 * Math.PI),
        rng(2 * Math.PI),
        rng(2 * Math.PI)
    ];
    const speeds = [
        rng(t.options.speed[0], t.options.speed[1]) * dr(),
        rng(t.options.speed[0], t.options.speed[1]) * dr(),
        rng(t.options.speed[0], t.options.speed[1]) * dr(),
        rng(t.options.speed[0], t.options.speed[1]) * dr()
    ];
    const h = () => {
        e.push(LN({ angle: angles, speed: speeds }, t.color));
        if (e.length > t.options.width) {
            e.shift();
        }
    };
    const n = () => {
        const {
            ctx: i,
            radius: s,
            centerX: h,
            centerY: n,
            options: o
        } = t;
        const r = s / 3;
        const a = (o.rotation * Math.PI) / 360;
        const { amplitude: d } = o;
        for (const l of e) {
            const { angle: $ } = l;
            const wave1 = $[0] * d + a;
            const wave2 = $[3] * d + a;
            const wave3 = $[1] * d * 2;
            const wave4 = $[2] * d * 2;
            const u = h - s * Math.cos(wave1);
            const p = n - s * Math.sin(wave1);
            const w = h - r * Math.cos(wave3);
            const _ = n - r * Math.sin(wave3);
            const v = h + r * Math.cos(wave4);
            const b = n + r * Math.sin(wave4);
            const c = h + s * Math.cos(wave2);
            const g = n + s * Math.sin(wave2);
            i.strokeStyle = l.color;
            i.beginPath();
            i.moveTo(u, p);
            i.bezierCurveTo(w, _, v, b, c, g);
            i.stroke();
        }
    };
    return { lines: e, angle: angles, speed: speeds, update: h, draw: n };
}
```

Comment: what version of firefox are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of firefox for developers